# Why would Sax Russell get into a relationship with Phyllis Boyle?

Tags: mars-trilogy, green-mars

In the *Mars Trilogy*, Saxifrage "Sax" Russell despised Phyllis Boyle. He is a brilliant scientist and a leader of the Green Mars movement. Because of his role among the First Hundred and as a "Green", Sax Russell is wanted by the authoritarian UNTA agency that controls economic development on Mars. His appearance is eventually altered so that he can hide and only a few people know his true name.

Phyllis Boyle is another member of the First Hundred. She is in favor of the increasingly authoritarian United Nations Office of Mars Affairs (UNOMA) and its successor, the corporate/quasi-fascist United Nations Transitional Authority (UNTA). This puts her at odds with many of the First Hundred, and the Greens (who want a Green livable Mars independent of Earth), and the Reds (who want to keep Mars in its original pre-terraformed state).

In the second book of the Mars Trilogy, Phyllis Boyle and Sax Russell engage in a brief sexual relationship. She does not know who he is at first because of his altered appearance even though the two of them worked closely together for years when they were among the first colonists on Mars. He knows who she is and that she might eventually recognize him by his manners, his personality, or something else.

Phyllis Boyle eventually realizes who she is dating.

> She turns Sax Russell over to UNTA security officials. They torture him, damage the verbal expression parts of his brain, and almost kill him. Phyllis Boyle was killed by by Kasei and Maya while they were saving Sax from torture.

Sax Russell despised Phyllis Boyle. He could not stand her harsh personality. He disliked the way she ingratiated herself with authoritarian government agencies by turning over her former friends to them. He hated that she supported UNOMA and UNTA control over Mars. He did not approve of her goals of wanting economic power over Mars.

She, on the other hand, almost certainly knew that UNTA used torture and arbitrary imprisonment against its political opponents. Maybe a second question is why she would turn Sax over to UNTA. I guess romantic partners are a lower priority to her than getting back in power.

**If Sax despised Phyllis, then why did he have a romantic and sexual relationship with her?**

Comment: Because people make shitty choices about their sexual partners?

Answer (score 3):

All the quotes below come from "Part 4, The Scientist as Hero" of Green Mars, but some are out of order.

At this point in the trilogy Sax has known Phyllis for decades, the scene takes place in 2091 while the first 100 landing is 2026. Even when you dislike someone having a history that stretches back that (including the training period) seventy years, many of them in close cramped quarters, both physically and psychologically, builds a closeness that you wouldn't get with a stranger.

> And besides although he did not especially like Phyllis, he did know her; there was that old First Hundred bond, the memories of those years together in Underhill.

Add to that Sax is taking euphoric drugs at the point of their first sexual encounter

> But Lindholm, now: he was a congenial fellow. He knew how to get along. Someone who could partake of a bottle of Utopian zinfandel, someone who could do his part to make a dinner party festive.

And Phyliss pursues him over the course of the evening, engineering multiple encounters that are all new territory for the introverted Sax

> And Phyllis was there by his side, grabbing his hand and pulling him out amongst the dancers... He had never danced in his life as far as he could recall.

> She leaned down and kissed him full on the mouth... In point of fact, no one had ever done that to him before.

So, he knows her. He's on drugs. She makes all the moves. Its his first time so doesn't know how to get out of it. And he's supposed to be someone else (Lindholm) who would no doubt be expected to be slightly in awe of the celebrity coming onto him. At this point Phyliss is both rich and famous, where as many of the first hundred are just famous (or infamous) and in hiding.

And as a comment on the question says, people make bad choices all the time. Even real Heroes like Sax.